# A JavaScript error occurred in the main process. TypeError: electron.BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension is not a function

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge, electronic-signature

When I introduced devtron into electron, the program reported an error。

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: electron.BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension is not a function
at Object.exports.install (/electron-quick-start/node_modules/devtron/api.js:13:35)
at App.<anonymous> (/electron-quick-start/main.js:6:24)
at App.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

I created electron for the first time. I cloned a project from GIT：
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

my code is like this

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')

app.on("ready", () => {
    require('devtron').install();
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1600,
        height: 1200,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools(); // 自动打开inspector
    ipcMain.on('message',(event,args) => {
        console.log(arg)
    })
})
```

my package.json is like this

```
{
      "name": "electron-quick-start",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A minimal Electron application",
      "main": "main.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --watch main.js --exec \"electron .\""
      },
      "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
      "keywords": [
        "Electron",
        "quick",
        "start",
        "tutorial",
        "demo"
      ],
      "author": "GitHub",
      "license": "CC0-1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^15.3.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I solved it with this answer:   https://github.com/electron-userland/devtron/issues/252

Answer (score 0):

[I solved it with this answer，click me see more.](https://github.com/electron-userland/devtron/issues/252)

```js
diff --git a/node_modules/devtron/api.js b/node_modules/devtron/api.js
index 3cdabe2..edf8b75 100644
--- a/node_modules/devtron/api.js
+++ b/node_modules/devtron/api.js
@@ -1,29 +1,27 @@
 const electron = require('electron')
+const path = require('path')
 
-exports.install = () => {
-  if (process.type === 'renderer') {
-    console.log(`Installing Devtron from ${__dirname}`)
-    if (electron.remote.BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions &&
-        electron.remote.BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions().devtron) return true
-    return electron.remote.BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(__dirname)
-  } else if (process.type === 'browser') {
+const resolve = (_dir) => path.resolve(process.cwd(), _dir)
+
+
+exports.install = (session) => {
+  if (process.type === 'renderer' || process.type === 'browser') {
     console.log(`Installing Devtron from ${__dirname}`)
-    if (electron.BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions &&
-        electron.BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions().devtron) return true
-    return electron.BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(__dirname)
+    if (session.defaultSession.getAllExtensions &&
+      session.defaultSession.getAllExtensions().devtron) return true
+    return session.defaultSession.loadExtension(resolve(__dirname))
   } else {
     throw new Error('Devtron can only be installed from an Electron process.')
   }
 }
 
-exports.uninstall = () => {
-  if (process.type === 'renderer') {
+exports.uninstall = (session) => {
+  if (process.type === 'renderer' || process.type === 'browser') {
     console.log(`Uninstalling Devtron from ${__dirname}`)
-    return electron.remote.BrowserWindow.removeDevToolsExtension('devtron')
-  } else if (process.type === 'browser') {
-    console.log(`Uninstalling Devtron from ${__dirname}`)
-    return electron.BrowserWindow.removeDevToolsExtension('devtron')
-  } else {
+    if (session.defaultSession.getAllExtensions &&
+      !session.defaultSession.getAllExtensions().devtron) return true
+    return session.defaultSession.removeExtension('devtron')
+  }else {
     throw new Error('Devtron can only be uninstalled from an Electron process.')
   }
 }
diff --git a/node_modules/devtron/manifest.json b/node_modules/devtron/manifest.json
index 24613a4..295f752 100644
--- a/node_modules/devtron/manifest.json
+++ b/node_modules/devtron/manifest.json
@@ -4,8 +4,11 @@
   "devtools_page": "static/devtron.html",
   "content_scripts": [
     {
-      "matches": ["*"],
-      "js": ["out/browser-globals.js"]
+      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
+      "js": ["out/browser-globals.js"],
+      "unsafe-inline": true
     }
-  ]
+  ],
+  "manifest_version": 2,
+  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' object-src 'sha256-oUhBdPf7Ru2sGu4k6v1SmxAkpoPTuzvsLrUqElYwDRE='"
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).